# In Vue multiple question, reverse one question options cause all question options change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

It is a Vue application that shows questions with multiple options, in each question, there is a button to reverse the options.

The full code is as below **:**

```
<template>
  <div class="">
      <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2" v-if="step==0">
        <div class="flex flex-row space-x-2">
          <button type="button" class="p-2 bg-blue-600 mx-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white rounded-md"  @click="step=1;handleQuestions(data)"><span>Next Step</span></button>
        </div>

        <div class="flex flex-row space-x-5">

              <el-input type="textarea" :rows="12" placeholder="Please input" v-model="data"> </el-input>

              <div class="w-1/5" >
                <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1" v-for="(item, index) in defaultOptions" :key="index">
                    <div class="flex flex-row space-x-5">
                      <el-input class="w-24" placeholder="label" v-model="item.label"></el-input>
                      <el-input class="w-24" placeholder="score" v-model="item.score"></el-input>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2 max-h-screen bg-white p-2 rounded-lg" v-if="step==1">
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between w-full">
            <button type="button" class="p-2 bg-blue-600 mx-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white rounded-md"  @click="step=0"><span>Previous Step</span></button>
          </div>
          <div class="overflow-y-auto flex flex-col space-y-2" >
            
              <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1" v-for="(question, index) in questions" :key="index">
                <div class=" text-base mb-2" >  
                  <span class="flex flex-row space-x-1" >
                      <span class="text-xl w-10"> {{index + 1}}. </span>
                      <!-- <InputEditor class="text-sm  w-full" :value="question.name" @input="updateEditor($event,'name')"></InputEditor> -->
                      <span class="text-xl w-5/6 w-full"> {{index + 1}} {{  question.name  }} </span>
                      <i class="el-icon-s-order" @click="reserveOptions(index)"> </i>
                  </span>
                </div>             
                <el-radio-group class="flex space-x-3" >
                    <el-radio v-for="(question, index2) in question.options" :key="index2" :label="question" style="width: 100%;">
                        {{ question.label }}
                    </el-radio>
                </el-radio-group>
              </div>
          </div>  
      </div>          

  </div>
</template>



<script >

export default {
  name: 'Editor',
  components: {  },
  data: function () {
    return {

      data:'',

      step:0,
      questions:[],

      defaultOptions:[
        {'label':'very bad','score':1},
        {'label':'not bad','score':0},
        {'label':'ok','score':1},
        {'label':'good','score':2},
        {'label':'best','score':3},
      ]
    }
  },

  methods: {

    handleQuestions(codes){
      let lines = codes.split('\n');
      let lineArray = [];
      let questions = [];
      for(let i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
          let line = lines[i].trimStart();
          if(line ===  ''){
            console.log('empty line',i,line);
          }else{
            console.log('line',line);
            lineArray.push(line);
          }
      }
      console.log('lineArray',lineArray);
      
      for(let i=0;i<lineArray.length;i++){
          let question = lineArray[i];
          questions.push({name:question,options: this.defaultOptions });          
      }
      this.questions = questions;
    },

    reserveOptions(index) {
      this.questions[index].options = this.questions[index].options.reverse();
    }, 


  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

In the first step, you can input some questions into the textarea components and then click the next button.

Sample Inputs **:**

1. I can quickly tell when I'm angry
2. I know how I look and behave when I’m angry
3. I can clearly distinguish between different degrees of happiness
4. I can tell the difference between being sad and being angry

---

In the second step, you will see the list of questions with reverse button

[image]

when clicking the reverse button, I expect the clicked question would reverse the options only in that specific question.  However, in this app, all the questions have reversed the options.

[image]

so strange, all the questions have reversed the options.

Comment: The code is working fine on my side. Only the clicked question's options are getting reversed. The only mistake I noticed in the question is that the data property's name should be `questions: [...]` not `question:[...]`. Can you provide any working fiddle to point out this behavior?

Comment: is this example exactly like the real code?
my guess is the options array in both questions must be referencing the same array in the real code.
if that's the case then you need to make a new options array for every question object.

Comment: @SherifHassan my original code (similar to my previous code) still have this problem. I pasted it again, would you see the original code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The way you are assigning the arrays, like `this.questions = questions;`, and `options: this.defaultOptions` leads to copying the same reference to each question's options array that's why every question is getting affected. So, create a new options array every time for each question.**

Another thing, If I got your logic correctly, you are splitting the lines and creating questions from every new line. So, you don't need to create a `lineArray` first and then loop on them, and then push to the local `questions` variable. These seem confusing as well as passing references while copying arrays. If the ultimate goal is to push every new line to the `questions` data array then why not do it in the first loop?

**I created a shallow copy of `defaultOptions` and then assign it to the question's options. If you have nestedness in your array or array is multidimensional, then created a deep copy instead.**

Replace your `handleQuestions` method with this and it will work-

```
handleQuestions(codes) {
  let lines = codes.split("\n");
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    let line = lines[i].trimStart();
    if (line === "") {
      console.log("empty line", i, line);
    } else {
      console.log("line", line);
      let options = [...this.defaultOptions]; // create TRUE copy
      this.questions.push({
        name: line,
        options: options
      });
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not see any issue with the code you posted and it is working fine. Here is the working demo. Can you please have a look and try to find the root cause of the issue you are facing.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    questions:[
      {'name':'question 1', options:[{'label':'a'},{'label':'b'},{'label':'c'}]},
      {'name':'question 2', options:[{'label':'a'},{'label':'b'},{'label':'c'}]},
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    reserveOptions(index) {
      this.questions[index].options = this.questions[index].options.reverse();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1" v-for="(question, index) in questions" :key="index">
    <div class=" text-base mb-2" >  
      <span class="flex flex-row space-x-1" >
        <span class="text-xl w-10"> {{ question.name }}. </span>
        <button @click="reserveOptions(index)">Reverse the order</button>
      </span>
    </div>             
    <div class="flex space-x-3" >
      <span v-for="(question, index2) in question.options" :key="index2" :label="question">
        {{ question.label }}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update :** As per the author's comment, Deep drive in to the original code he pasted and found the culprit.

```
questions.push({name:question,options: this.defaultOptions });
```

This is the statement which is causing the issue, As all the `options` property in the `questions` array objects holding the same address. It is updating the source `defaultOptions` for all the question options.

To make it work, You can assign the deep copy of the `defaultOptions` and it will work like a champ. Change that statement to **:**

```
questions.push({name:question,options: structuredClone(this.defaultOptions) });
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    step:0,
    data:'',
    defaultOptions:[
      {'label':'very bad','score':1},
      {'label':'not bad','score':0},
      {'label':'ok','score':1},
      {'label':'good','score':2},
      {'label':'best','score':3},
    ],
    questions:[]
  },
  methods: {
    reserveOptions(index) {
      console.log(this.questions[index].options);
      this.questions[index].options = this.questions[index].options.reverse();
    },
    handleQuestions(codes) {
      let lines = codes.split('\n');
      let lineArray = [];
      let questions = [];
      for(let i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
        let line = lines[i].trimStart();
        if (line) {
          lineArray.push(line);
        }
      }

      for(let i=0;i<lineArray.length;i++){
        let question = lineArray[i];
        questions.push({name:question,options: structuredClone(this.defaultOptions) });          
      }
      this.questions = questions;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="step === 0">
    <button type="button" class="p-2 bg-blue-600 mx-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white rounded-md"  @click="step=1;handleQuestions(data)"><span>Next Step</span></button>

    <div>
      <textarea rows="12" placeholder="Please input" v-model="data"></textarea>
      <div v-for="(item, index) in defaultOptions" :key="index">
        <input placeholder="label" v-model="item.label"/>
        <input placeholder="score" v-model="item.score"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div v-if="step === 1">
    <div>
      <button type="button" @click="step = 0"><span>Previous Step</span></button>
    </div>
    <div v-for="(question, index) in questions" :key="index">
      <div>
        <span> {{index + 1}}. </span>
        <span> {{index + 1}} {{question.name}} </span>
        <button @click="reserveOptions(index)">Reverse</button>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(question, index2) in question.options" :key="index2" :label="question" style="width: 100%;">
          {{ question.label }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your test, it did work on my side. But my original code (similar to my previous code) still have this problem. I pasted it again, would you see the original code again.

Comment: @user824624 I updated the answer with the working code snippet. I hope it will work as per your expectation now.